# Determine if an int is among a list or a range

Tags: c#

How to determine if a given `int` corresponds to a given 'pattern'. The 'pattern' can be composed of int or range of int.

Here is the method's signature.

```
    //Eg of pattern 
    // 10,12,14,16
    // [10-20];21;23
    public bool IsInPattern(int inputToTest, string pattern)
    {
        //Todo
    }
```

The pattern below is defined as a string with a list of inner pattern separated by ';'. Inner pattern can either be an int or a range [lowerBound-upperBound].

I believe that can be reached with regex but I didn't not succeed in doing it. Also, I prefer a solution more elegant than something like `if subPattern.StartWith('[') then lowerBound = subPattern.Substring` etc...

Comment: _"we can imagine changing this"_ So what is your question? Do you need that string or can it be changed to an `IEnumerable<int>`, then you just need to use `Contains`.

Comment: You need to build some kind of "pattern parser" yourself. As far as I know, there's nothing built into the framework to do this.

Comment: Yes we can have an 'IEnumerable<int>', but the question will then be, how to populate it. My initial input will remains a string, the syntaxe of this string can be changed in order to meet the need (say we can have litterally 10 or 12 or 13 ; we can also have something like [10-20];21;23)

Comment: @Toto: So what question do you want to be answered here, the one how to extract the int or the range from the string with these patterns or the one how to check if an int is in a list or a range of other ints? Don't aks too much. It might be _"too broad"_ otherwise.

Comment: @Tim, you're right. I realize that actually I am asking myself how to parse the pattern, thus I modified the question

Answer (score 2):

I would write this as two methods rather than having pattern.

```
public bool IsInSequence(int inputToTest, IEnumerable<int> sequence)
{
    return sequence.Contains(inputToTest);
}

public bool IsInRange(int inputToTest, int start, int end)
{
    return inputToTest>= start && inputToTest<=end ;
}
```

Comment: If the range is large then your IsInRange method will be extremely inefficient, as it creates a collection of all required integers. It would be far better to test for ">= start" and "<= end"

Comment: `return inputToTest >= start && inputToTest <= end;` would be better.

Comment: But how does this answer the question how to extract the range or the number from the string with patterns like `0 or 12 or 13 or ...` or `[10-20];21;23]`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is not the question being asked. My answer solves the problem in different way. Why to over complicate things with string based pattern saying "to" etc. If at all OP needs to extract range from string let him ask. He hasn't asked anything yet about that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: But actually it _is_ what OP asks. He has even edited his question meanwhile to claraify it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple parsing like this.

```
public bool IsInPattern(int inputToTest, string pattern)
{
    var numbers = new List<int>();
    var tokens = pattern.Split(new []{",", " ", "or"}, 
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    bool to_flag = false;
    foreach(var t in tokens)
    {
        int n;
        if (Int32.TryParse(t, out n))
        {
            if (to_flag) 
                numbers.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(numbers.Last() + 1, 
                                                  n - numbers.Last()));
            else 
                numbers.Add(n);

            to_flag = false;
        }
        else if (t == "to") to_flag = true;
        else throw new Exception("invalid pattern");
    }
    return numbers.Contains(inputToTest);
}
```

And a test:

```
IsInPattern(11, "10,12,14,16"); // false
IsInPattern(12, "10,12,14,16"); // true
IsInPattern(11, "10 to 20 or 21 or 23");// true
IsInPattern(22, "10 to 20 or 21 or 23");// false
```

Answer (score 0):

may be something like:

```
pattern.Split(',').Where(sub=>sub == inputToTest.ToString())
```

This way perfectly works if there is a *range* or there is just *sequence of arbitrary integers*, separated by some predefined separator (, in this concrete case)

Comment: "102" contains "10" but it's not the same.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: correct, changed just code

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (this is from head, so it might not work without modifications):

```
public bool IsInPattern(int inputToTest, string pattern)
{
    if (pattern.Contains(","))
        return pattern.Split(',').Contains(inputToTest.ToString());
    else
    {
        var temp = pattern.Split(';');
        if (temp.Contains(inputToTest.ToString()))
            return true;
        else
        {
            temp = temp.RemoveAll(x => !x.Contains("-"));
            foreach (var x in temp)
            {
                string[] a = x.Split("-").Select(x => x.Trim('[',']')).ToArray();
                if (IsInRange(inputToTest, int.Parse(a[0]), int.Parse(a[1])))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public bool IsInRange(int inputToTest, int start, int end)
{
    return inputToTest >= start && inputToTest <=end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Specification Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) when I need to check some value satisfies different conditions. Specification looks like:

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T value);
}
```

For each set of conditions you create different specification classes. Here you will need range specification (I will use `int` as generic type in order to simplify things):

```
public class RangeSpecification : ISpecification<int>
{
    private readonly int _from;
    private readonly int _to;

    public RangeSpecification(int from, int to)
    {
        _to = to;
        _from = from;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(int value)
    {
        return _from <= value && value <= _to;
    }
}
```

And specification for list of values (we also can consider single value as a list specification):

```
public class InSpecification : ISpecification<int>
{
    private readonly int[] _values;

    public InSpecification(params int[] values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(int value)
    {
        return _values.Contains(value);
    }
}
```

That is already enough to test conditions like:

```
var rangeSpec = new RangeSpecification(10, 15);
var is13inRange = rangeSpec.IsSatisfiedBy(13); // true
var is20inRange = rangeSpec.IsSatisfiedBy(20); // false
var inSpec = new InSpecification(1,2,5,8);
var is13inList = inSpec.IsSatisfiedBy(13); // false
```

But in order to build more interesting conditions you need to implement conditional logic:

```
public class OrSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>
{
    private readonly ISpecification<T> _left;
    private readonly ISpecification<T> _right;

    public OrSpecification(ISpecification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
    {
        _right = right;
        _left = left;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(T value)
    {
        return _left.IsSatisfiedBy(value) || _right.IsSatisfiedBy(value);
    }
}
```

This specification will help us to build OR conditions to check if value satisfies any provided specifications. I also use extension methods to build specifications:

```
public static class SpecificationExtensions
{
    public static ISpecification<T> Or<T>(
        this ISpecification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
    {
        return new OrSpecification<T>(left, right);
    }
}
```

Now we can build something like:

```
var spec = new RangeSpecification(10, 15).Or(new InSpecification(1,2,5,8));
var result = spec.IsSatisfiedBy(8); // true
```

All we need now is to parse specifications from your string:

```
public class SpecificationParser
{
    public static ISpecification<int> Parse(string input)
    {
        var parts = input.Split(';');
        return parts.Aggregate(ParseSpec(parts[0]), 
                               (spec, s) => spec.Or(ParseSpec(s)));
    }

    private static ISpecification<int> ParseSpec(string s)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(s, @"\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            int from = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
            int to = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
            return new RangeSpecification(from, to);
        }

        return new InSpecification(s.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray());
    }
}
```

That's it. Now you can parse specification from string and check if value satisfies it:

```
var spec1 = SpecificationParser.Parse("10, 12, 14, 16");
spec1.IsSatisfiedBy(11); // false

var spec2 = SpecificationParser.Parse("[10-20];21;23,25");
spec2.IsSatisfiedBy(9); // false
spec2.IsSatisfiedBy(19); // true
spec2.IsSatisfiedBy(22); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with different implementations of IPatternInterpretter. PatternInterpretter's Interpret method inputs the string expression and returns its Func representation by processing the string expression.

You should implement IPatternInterpretter for every different kind of pattern string. After all, you can write a PatternInterpretterFactory that inputs a single string pattern and decides which interpretter to instantiate.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string commaSeperatedPattern = "10,12,14,16";
        const string literallyExpressedPattern = "10 to 20 or 21 or 23";

        int input = 10;

        var commaSeperatedFunc = new CommaSeperatedPatternInterpretter().Interpret(commaSeperatedPattern);
        var literallyExpressedFunc = new LiterallyExpressedPatternInterpretter().Interpret(literallyExpressedPattern);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CommaSeperatedResult: {0} \nLiterallyExpressedResult: {1}",
                                        commaSeperatedFunc(input),
                                        literallyExpressedFunc(input)));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}



public interface IPatternInterpretter
{
    Func<int, bool> Interpret(string pattern);
}

/// <summary>
/// Patterns like "10,12,14,16"
/// </summary>
public class CommaSeperatedPatternInterpretter : IPatternInterpretter
{
    public Func<int, bool> Interpret(string pattern)
    {
        Func<int, bool> result = (input) => pattern.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim())).Contains(input);
        return result;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Patterns like "10 to 20 or 21 or 23"
/// </summary>
public class LiterallyExpressedPatternInterpretter : IPatternInterpretter
{
    public Func<int, bool> Interpret(string pattern)
    {
        Func<int, bool> result = (x) => false;
        List<string> items = pattern.Split(' ').Select(x => x.Trim().ToLower()).ToList();

        var ors = new List<int>();
        var intervals = new List<Array>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = items[i];

            if (item.Equals("or") && i < items.Count-1)
            {
                ors.Add(int.Parse(items[i + 1]));
            }
            else if (item.Equals("to") && i < items.Count-1 && i > 0)
            {
                intervals.Add(new int[] {int.Parse(items[i - 1]), int.Parse(items[i + 1])});
            }
        }
        return x => ors.Contains(x) || intervals.Any(i => x > (int) i.GetValue(0) && x < (int) i.GetValue(1));
    }
}
```